# Use API Twitter to send Tweet in Sandbox

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2

I'm using API twitter to send Tweet on my profile and it works.
I read the [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update) but I don't find any method to send "test" tweet.

I'd like to create some fake tweets to check if my code is working properly.

At the moment I use `.post("statuses/update"`

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to test the APIs. You have to use Twitter developer app Credentials The detail regarding the app permission and developer can be found in [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-portal/overview).

Comment: I have the credentials and my code works properly. But I'd like to post twit to test some futures without remove immediately from my status

Comment: So can you provide me with more details about exactly what you trying to do? If you are able to send tweets using API then what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I'd like to send twit visible only to me. I don't want to send twit like "test" it's  antoher test and so on. O remove immediately

Comment: Hi, I understand that now. As per my knowledge that is not possible. You can tweet something that is visible;e to you only because if that is possible then why do they demand the credentials of the app and token etc in the request?   But you can delete the tweet whenever you want. You can explore more about tweets at [link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/lookup/introduction).

The APIs just allow tweeting when you give them the credentials of the authenticated user. So the tweet will be visible normally. Hope so now it will make sense about your scenario.